# heroku facebook app run locally throws blocked frame error on fb login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, node.js, heroku

I've followed the steps in the [Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#working-locally) for node.js as well as ruby and run into the same issue. Am able setup the basic applicatin and run it locally using 127.0.0.01:5000

However, when the fb login button is clicked, i see the following error in the browser

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing
>   a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

Since the fb login button is put into a frame by the fb css (or something else - not sure) I don't seem to ave much control over this

Surely , someone else has run into this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that when you are connecting with your local host, you are using the http protocol. If that's the case, then it would make sense that a frame with a higher security (https) can't be accessed from a http frame. Try deploying to heroku, which will be https, and see if that solves your problem. Hope that helps!